# Prove: Let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$. If $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is differentiable on $I$ with $f'(x)=0$, then $f$ must be real.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$. If $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is differentiable on $I$ with $f'(x)=0$, then $f$ must be real.

In proving that $f$ must be constant on $I$ given that $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is differentiable on $I$ with $f'(x)=0$, the author states we can assume $f$ is real. This should follow from:

We can write $f = f_1 + if_2$ (where $f_1,f_2$ are both real). Then $f'(x_0) = f_1'(x_0) + i f_2'(x_0)$ by linearity of differentiation $(1)$.

However, I don't see why $(1)$ imply that $f$ must be real. Could someone help me out ?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing something? $f(x) = i$ isn't real, but $f'(x) = 0$. What's the context of this question? Is it from a book?

Comment: By splitting $f$ into its real and imaginary part, we can _assume_ that $f$ is real when deducing constancy from $f'(x) \equiv 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Makes sense. This is probably what the author meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ need not be real at all. What the author means is this.

Suppose we have already proved the implication "$f' = 0$ implies $f$ is constant" for real-valued functions $f$, and now we want to prove it for complex-valued functions $f$.

Take a complex-valued function $f$ and decompose it into a sum $f = f_1 + i f_2$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are real. Since the implication above is already known for real-valued functions, and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are real-valued, it follows that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are constants. But then $f$ is a constant too, qed.

And now it only remains to prove that which we assumed in the beginning: that the implication holds for real-valued functions $f$.

Comment: Thanks Dan, this was just what I needed in order to understand the procedure.